# How does Siri come up with contact suggestions?

Tags: siri

Are they recent from days, months?  How long ago?  Are they calls, text, FaceTime?

Answer (score 2):

## Relevant people

As Apple specified on its website page dedicated to iOS 9, with your Siri suggestions you can

> See the contacts you **talk** with **most**, those you **talked** to **last**, or even
>   those you’re next **scheduled** to **meet**

I'd definitely suggest you to have a look to all that Siri suggestions include from [here](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/), in fact it doesn't just suggest you Contacts, but also

- Places
- Apps
- News

Hope this helped you!